# Prevent subprocess of subprocess from writing to stdout

Tags: python, subprocess, stdout

I'm calling a subprocess and want to disable any output to my shell. I'm trying to do this with:

```
 with tempfile.TemporaryFile() as tempf:
        proc = Popen(cmd, stdout=tempf, stderr=tempf)
        proc.communicate()
```

But there is still some output (but less than normally) appearing at the terminal. Could the problem be that the called process uses `os.execvp`? Any suggestions to fully disable the output for all subprocesses?

**Note**

Redirecting to devnull is a better way of disabling output:

```
with open(os.devnull, 'w') as tempf:
    proc = Popen(cmd, stdout=tempf, stderr=tempf)
    proc.communicate()
```

**Question answered!**

Very simple solution: The called process uses CORBA and the server is actually printing out.

Comment: Your example is using ``popen()``, not ``subprocess``

Comment: subprocess inherit the stdout's and stderr's from their parents by default. Short of going on the hunt for wild ttys, there's no way a subsubprocess can get your stdin. Which programs are you executing?

Comment: @Carpetsmoker: Popen lives in module subprocess in newer python versions

Comment: @Carpetsmoker Nope, notice the upper-case `P`. He just executed `from subprocess import Popen`. `os.popen` does not take any keyword arguments anyways, and would therefore fail immediately.

Comment: Side note: Sending stderr and stdout to a temporary file is not a good way to discard output. Just open `os.devnull` for writing.

Comment: @MarceloCantos: Thanks for your advice, didn't know this will work.

Comment: @phihag I'm calling "Salome", a pre processor fur numerical simulation. I'm using the command "runSession" as described here: http://docs.salome-platform.org/salome_6_4_0/gui/KERNEL/SALOME_Application.html

Comment: Unfortunately, writing to `/dev/null` does not solve the issue.

Comment: @ms4py Switching to /dev/null won't change the output, but will prevent a huge temporary file from being created. Salome looks to be really powerful - can you reproduce the problem with a command that's widely available/pre-installed? If not, you should post the output of `strace -ff python your-python-program.py` to [pastebin](http://pastebin.com) or so, so that we can detect how salome is writing stuff out. As I said, my guess would be that a component is going hunting for wild ttys (for secure password input or so)

Comment: @phihag `strace` is running for about 5 minutes now (execution usually needs about 30 secs) and is producing million lines of output. Another idea?

Comment: strace will make it slower, but only by a factor of about 10. Are you using the `-o` option? You can also limit the output with `-e trace=fork,execve,open`. Also, you don't have to strace everything - you can abort strace and the program as soon as the error case (any output at all) occurs.

Comment: @phihag: Well, I have an output with >100 MB (output is already limited).

Comment: Well, 100MB is handle-able. Can you upload that somewhere? I'd grep for `tty` or `/proc/`. By the way, have you absolutely excluded the possibility that another part of your top-level python program is causing the output? If you comment out the lines you included in this question, do you still get the offending output?

Comment: Oh, very simple solution. Salome is using CORBA and the server wasn't started with redirecting output to `/dev/null`. Thanks for the suggestions :-)

Answer (score -2, accepted):

As described above, the called process was calling a server, which produced the mysterios stdout.