# how to hide stdout of subprocess on windows

Tags: python, subprocess

I know linux solutions of opening a /dev/null and redirecting stout to it.
(like [Prevent subprocess of subprocess from writing to stdout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9153796/prevent-subprocess-of-subprocess-from-writing-to-stdout) or similar ones)
What is the solution in windows?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Use the same approach, but use [`os.devnull`](http://docs.python.org/library/os.html#os.devnull) which is the portable solution.  On Windows this will send the output to [`NUL`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/313115/505154).

In fact, this solution is already recommended in the question you linked to:

```
with open(os.devnull, 'w') as tempf:
    proc = Popen(cmd, stdout=tempf, stderr=tempf)
    proc.communicate()
```